# docker nginx forward port to container error

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Looking for some help regarding configuring Nginx to forward incoming requests on port 10000 to an application running in a container.

I have a docker image containing 3 containers. 1st container being an Nginx server, 2nd flask application and the 3rd being a Dataiku DSS server.

The flask application works as should and I can connect via port 443 but when trying to connect to the Dataiku DSS server I get 502 error "Bad Request".

I can run the DSS Server container on its own by running `docker run 10000:10000 dataiku/dss` and everything works as expected. I can connect via 127.0.0.1:10000. I have also tried the Nginx configuration while running the DSS server completely separate from the project but still no luck.

compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  flask:
    build: ./flask
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    image: trac
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=Trac
    expose:
      - 8080
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - c:/trac_temp_files:/temp_files

  dss:
    build: ./dss
    image: dss
    container_name: dss
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 10000
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
    depends_on:
      - nginx

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "10000:10000"
```

nginx conf:

```
server {
    # Host/port on which to expose Data Science Studio to users
    listen 10000 ssl;
    ssl_certificate wildcard.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key wildcard.key;
    location / {
        # Base url of the Data Science Studio installation
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:10000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # Allow long queries
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        # Allow large uploads
        client_max_body_size 0;
        # Allow protocol upgrade to websocket
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate wildcard.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key wildcard.key;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to docker so I'm wondering if there is something I have miss understood.

I'm trying to follow what is recommended by Dataiku about connecting via SSL but I'm assuming the guide is not assuming you are using their docker image https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/installation/proxies.html#reverse-proxy

Also, the reason for using docker is the machine where all of this will be hosted has no internet access and is only visible to the network I am on.

Any help would be awesome as I'm a little stuck without this working.

**UPDATE:**

The desired outcome of what I am trying to achieve is for the user to be able to connect to either application.

For example:

```
www.example.com:5000 = app1
www.example.com:5001 = app2
```

If the above is not possible, how would I achieve something like

```
www.example.com/app1 = app1
www.example.com/app2 = app2
```

Comment: The ip address of a container in a 'composition' is the name you give it in your compose file. In your case, this would change `0.0.0.0` to `dss`. Docker takes care of domain name resolution for you. Nginx can't run on port 10000, that's the port for DSS, and remove the `expose` entry and the `ports` entries from everything.

Comment: If nginx can't listen on port 10000 how would I allow users to connect to IP:10000?? Again new to this so apologies if that's a silly question

Comment: Your docker instances are really just Linux processes running on the same machine -- you can't run 2 processes on the same port. Your users connect to Nginx on 80/443, not 10k. The 10k port is for Nginx to talk to dss.

Comment: Ah I see. How would I go about getting a user to be able to connect to dss and flask_app running on the same nginx server. Would I need to somehow sub domain? Like IP/app? I was always under the impression you could just point to a different port for a different app.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I changed `http://0.0.0.0:10000/` to `dss:10000` and get `invalid URL prefix in conf`

Comment: You don't need users to connect to dss and flask -- the Nginx container is your ingress point and it routes traffic to the other services. I don't know why you're getting that error, but it's a syntax error -- a typo in your config -- not an underlying problem with the intent.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I think I may have completely confused myself with how all of this stuff works. The outcome I want is for the user to be able to connect to each app. as they are 2 different applications, the applications do not talk directly to each other. Will update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to expose ports in nginx because you are using it as proxy server. And also, in your docker compose file add the volume as following for nginx config file:

```
volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```